# Cannot implicitly convert type C# .Net Core Issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

What I'm trying to do is make an api service using .NET Core where I am making an array from a database .... I'm getting a 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Action[] to SynCore.DbrAction[]'.

Am I going in the right direction? I'm trying to make a api service that my Angular client can consume.

**Action Controller**

```
    public class ActionsController : ControllerBase
{
    private IActionService _actionService;
    public ActionsController(IActionService actionService)
    {
        _actionService = actionService;
    }

    //GET: api/Actions
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetActions(string userId, string sessionId)
    {
        // TODO: Figure out when recurseOnMenus is true, pass it accordingly instead of forcing false.
        DbrAction[] dbrActions = _actionService.GetActions(userId, sessionId);
        return Ok(dbrActions);
    }
```

**Action Service**

```
public interface IActionService
{
    Action[] GetActions(string userId, string sessionId);

}

public class ActionService : IActionService
{
    private DataContext _context;

    public ActionService(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public DbrAction[] GetActions(string sessionId)
    {
        UserStateHelper ush = new UserStateHelper();
        UserState us = ush.CreateUserState(sessionId);
        XioTable xt = new XioTable(us, T.User);
        DbrUser user = (DbrUser)xt.LoadSingleRow(us.UserTag, C.User_DefaultActionTag);

        Actions[] actions = {};
        List<DbrAction> dbrActions = new List<DbrAction>();
        xt = new XioTable(us, T.Action);
        xt.SelectCols(C.Action_Description, C.Action_ActionName, C.Action_FolderTag, C.Action_ActionType, C.Action_PrimaryTable);
        xt.LoadData();
        foreach (DbrAction action in xt.GetAllRows(C.Action_FolderTag))
        {
            if (!DbrAction.IsTableDeprecated(action.PrimaryTable))
            {
                if (action.ActionType == ActionType.View || action.ActionType == ActionType.Dashboard)
                    dbrActions.Add(action);
            }
        }
        us.Completed(LogEntryType.GetStartupProfileData, null);
        return dbrActions.ToArray();
    }

    public Action[] GetActions(string userId, string sessionId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Welp, `ActionService#GetActions(string,string)` returns `Action[]`, not `DbrAction[]`...

Comment: Your interface `IActionService` expose `Action[] GetActions(string userId, string sessionId)`, but your implementation `Action[] GetActions(string userId, string sessionId)` throws `NotImplementedException`, is the sample up-to-date?

Comment: @FrankNielsen yes it's up to date; I added that implementation because I'm not exactly sure what to do there.

Comment: Is it a runtime/execution error, or compile error?

Comment: But change the `Action[]` return on the interface `IActionService` and the impl. `ActionService` to `DbrAction[]`

Comment: use " var" instead of  "DbrAction[]"  in controller GetActions